# iOS video player metadata

Tags: iphone, ios, video, html5-video

My question is if there is any built-in interpretation of metadata by the video player in iOS. I know one can add meta-data to a video and interpret it within a custom application as shown [here](http://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/).

In iOS on ipod or iphone, an HTML video is opened within the native player. I would like to display a message above or below the video for a short duration at the beginning. Since I cannot control the native player I thought there might be some built in metadata interpretation that could be used to perform this. I have not been able to find any information on this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The blog you've posted includes details on using the native player MPMoviePlayerController to display meta data, which is pretty cool actually. You learn something new every day! If you're making a Phonegap App I suppose you could write a plugin to do this?

Or alternatively, have a look at this other OS question which appears to suggest that it is possible - though not seemingly with metadata embedded in the actual video. Apparently this works on iOS.

[Reading metadata from the <track> of an HTML5 <video> using Captionator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370260/reading-metadata-from-the-track-of-an-html5-video-using-captionator)