# firefox XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing

I am getting an error when reading file with ajax, it gets data successfully but firefox throws an error as well:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: 
http://localhost/xampp/gwp/subtitles/sintel-de.vtt
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I tried adding dataType: "text", but it doesnt help.

subtitle.vtt file:

```
WEBVTT

0
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:12.000
This is a subtitle.

1
00:00:18.700 --> 00:00:21.500
This blade has a dark past.
```

This is an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url//url to subtitle.vtt
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function( data ) {



}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

});
```

Error only happens in firefox.

Comment: here a post that speek vtt file i suppose that you create a new hidden tag video and put your vtt source- link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370260/reading-metadata-from-the-track-of-an-html5-video-using-captionator

Comment: You need to have your server send the correct mime header for the file you read

Comment: How do I send a mime header? As you can see from my code, I am just loading a vtt file with ajax. File content loads successfully, but only firefox throws this error (which doesnt affect anything, but it shouldnt be there).

Comment: It throws the error because it does not get the mimetype text/plain from the server and then it needs the data to be XML and it is not. Set .vtt as text/plain on the server

Comment: In your `.htaccess` add: `<IfModule mod_mime.c> AddType text/vtt vtt </IfModule>` - see https://htaccessbook.com/useful-htaccess-rules/ - This fixed it for me.